# Partial derivatives - Chain rule

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f(x, y, z)=e^{xz}\tan (yz)$ and $x=g(s, t)$, $y=h(s, t)$, $z=k(s, t)$. We set $m(s, t)=f(g(s, t), h(s, t), k(s, t))$. Find a formula for $m_{st}$ using the chain rule and verify that the result is symmetric as for $s$ and $t$.

I have done the following:

After using the chain rule I got $$m_{st}=f_{xx}g_{t}g_{s}+f_{xy}(h_{t}g_{s}+g_{t}h_{s})+f_{xz}(k_{t}g_{s}+g_{t}k_{s})+f_{yy}h_{t}h_{s}+f_{yz}(k_{t}h_{s}+h_{t}k_{s})+f_{zz}k_{t}k_{s}f_{x}g_{st}+f_{y}h_{st}+f_{z}k_{st}$$

Is this correct??

How can we vrify that the result is symmetric as for $s$ and $t$??

Comment: It simply means that you find both $m_{st}$ and $m_{ts}$ and show that they are the same.

Comment: To verify it we have to find $m_{ts}$, we cannot conclude it from the formula we found for $m_{st}$, right?? @CheeHan

Comment: I think they would be the same, but you are merely swapping indices only for $m_{ts}$, but if you want 100% sure, then better do it properly :)